# Ajax json to MVC5 controller: Passing object containing a collection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Folks, I've attempted this on MVC4 and MVC5.

I need to pass an object with a few properties and a collection from the client to the controller.

I've defined the model in C# as:

```
public enum RequestMode { ReadOnly = 0, Edit = 1}

public class DataRequest
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public RequestMode Mode { get; set; }
    public List<PageRequest> PageRequests { get; set; }

    public DataRequest()
    {
        PageRequests = new List<PageRequest>();
    }
}

public class PageRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PageCurrent { get; set; }
    public int RowCountPerPage { get; set; }
}
```

The MVC Controller is defined as (just using it to set a breakpoint to check the request values):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(DataRequest request)
{
    return new JsonResult();
}
```

The Index.cshtml client contains the ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RequestMode = { ReadOnly: 0, Edit: 1 };

    var dataRequest = { ProjectId: 17, Mode: RequestMode.Edit, PageRequests: new Array() };
    var pageRequest = { TableId: 3165, PageCurrent: 4, RowCountPerPage: 30 };
    dataRequest.PageRequests.push(pageRequest);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            data: dataRequest,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: '/Home/Test',
            success: function (data) {
            },
            fail: function (data) {

            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

I start debugging, the page loads and my breakpoint in the controller Test method gets hit.

In the debugger, the request object shows up as:
    Mode: Edit
    PageRequests: Count = 1
    ProjectId: 17

When I expand the PageRequests collection property, I see:
    {Mvc5WebTest.Controllers.PageRequest}
        Id: 0
        PageCurrent: 0
        RowsPerPage: 0

I would expect the PageRequest object to be populated with the values I've set (i.e. 3165, 4, 30)

Using Fiddler, I see that the complete DataRequest object is getting turned into Json correctly, but it seems that the MVC controller can't turn it back into the C# object.

As a workaround, I can modify the ajax call on the client to
    var cdr = JSON.stringify(dataRequest);

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { jsonRequest: cdr },
    ...
```

And then in the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test(string jsonRequest)
{
    var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataRequest>(jsonRequest);
    return new JsonResult();
}
```

This works, but I'd rather not pass the data as a string.

Can anyone shed some light as to what is going on and what I need to do to get the collection populated?

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're posting JSON data, you have to convert the object to string by using `JSON.stringify` and declare the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(dataRequest),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/Home/Test',
        success: function (data) {
        },
        fail: function (data) {

        }
});
```

I also noticed that in C# code, you defined `PageRequest` as

```
public class PageRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PageCurrent { get; set; }
    public int RowCountPerPage { get; set; }
}
```

While in js,

```
var pageRequest = { TableId: 3165, PageCurrent: 4, RowCountPerPage: 30 };
```

There is a conflict between `Id` in C# and `TableId` in js. You will have to use one or the other.

Comment: The trick was to both JSON.stringify and set the content type. The Id vs TableId conflict only occurred in the code I posted (sorry). Thanks for the help marko and vbn.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify that you're sending JSON over because the default content type is string:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        data: dataRequest,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/Home/Test',
        success: function (data) {
        },
        fail: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: When I add the contentType, the Test controller method doesn't get called.

Comment: @user3442969 Did you stringify your JSON with: JSON.stringify(dataRequest)?