# MVC Tabs and Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, models

Im quite new to MVC and have this huge application which requires using tabs and partial views . I have a ViewModel whose fields are lists of my EF classes. Im passing this view model class (ProjInfoVM) into my ProjInfo View. The view has 3 tabs which are form representing each of the EF Classes- they all require to be posted back for submission. **My first challenge** is getting the forms to display{ I already created the 3 strongly typed partial views} but dont know how to display them as i keep getting the error :
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SMS2.Models.ProjectInfoVM', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SMS2.Models.ProjResc' 
**My Second Challenge** is how to post the individual forms back to the controller - here i have no idea on how to achieve this... I need help

Below is my code :

ProjInfoVM.cs

```
public partial class ProjectInfoVM
    {
        public ProjCourse ProjCourse { get; set; }
        public ProjDocument ProjDocuments { get; set; }
        public ProjResc ProjRescs { get; set; }
    }
```

ProjResc Partial View

```
@model SMS2.Models.ProjResc

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>ProjResc</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RescId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RescId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RescId)
            </div>
    .....
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

.... Same format applies to the remaining 2 Partial{_ProjDoc and _ProjCourses}

ProjResc.cs {Same applies to the other two classes}

```
 public partial class ProjResc
    {
        public int RescId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SponsorId { get; set; }
        public decimal StipendAmt { get; set; }
        public string StipendFreq { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have my ProjInfo Controller with Action ProjInfo as below :

```
 public ActionResult ProjInfo()
        {

            ProjectInfoVM vm = new ProjectInfoVM();
           ...Populate vm contents here....           

            return PartialView(vm);
        }
```

and my ProjInfo View as below...

```
@model SMS2.Models.ProjectInfoVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProjInfo";
}
    <div class="panel panel-default tabs">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#tab-first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Project Resources</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Project Restrictions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Project Documents</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-four" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Project Courses</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="panel-body tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-first">

                                    <h2>Partial View content  : @Model.ProjCourse.CourseName</h2>

                                   @Html.Partial("_ProjCourse", Model.ProjCourse)
                                                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-second">

                                    @Html.Partial("_ProjResc", Model.ProjResc)

                                </div>.......
```

I keep getting this error..

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SMS2.Models.ProjectInfoVM', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SMS2.Models.ProjResc'
```

Can someone shed light into where im missing it alltogether...Please

Comment: can you show us your ProjInfo.cshtml view . the @model statement in particular.
And to submit all fields from both partial view you should include them in the same Form block

Comment: I have edited it to include the @model statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the partial view you have @model SMS2.Models.ProjResc that should be changed to @model ProjectInfoVM

For the second part check to overloads of Html.BeginForm() you can specify the controller and the action which will process your post.
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks.... the partial views are now rendered correctly....Can u elaborate on how to have each form posted individually to the controller action

Comment: Thanks.. I got the posting part solved... did it by having a separate form on each partial view and redirecting it to different controller actions..  like so   **@using (Html.BeginForm("ProjInfo", "Project", new { id = 1 }))
{.** Thanks

Comment: Posting form in tabs is probably not the best from UI prospective, because will reload the whole page. You can investigate how you can call the same action but by ajax post request using jQuery

Comment: @ Lyubomir Velchev can you please explain how i can go about that... cos i have 4 tabs contatining fractions of my ViewModel Class, I dont want each for to hold the entire Viewmodel Info as it will be difficult to post( i guess).. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: There is no problem if you have the entire view model in each partial view. But posting will still reload your page and possibly loose your current tab. You can have a look at that example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540739/ajax-json-to-mvc5-controller-passing-object-containing-a-collection?answertab=active#tab-top